# How to merge/group two values of array objects by dates

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

I'm trying to display a graph using [Amchart Multiple Values](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/multiple-value-axes/?theme=dataviz) the information come from ElasticSearch. And this is my JS code:

```
$.get(URI).then(resp => JSON.parse(resp))
            .then(values => {
                console.log(values)
                var data = [],
                values.map(e => e._source) //From Elastic the info is inside '_source' key  
                    .map((n, i) => {
                        n.date = moment(n.date).format('Y-MM-DD');
// I'm trying to format date, because it cames with Hour:Min:Sec and if I 
// try to compare dates it wont be equal (NOT USING IN THIS ATTEMPT)
                        if (n.warehouse.name === 'General') {
                            data.push({date: n.date, general: n.assessment});
                        } else {
                            data.push({date: n.date, intransit: n.assessment});
                        }

                    });

            })
            .fail(err => console.error(err.response));
```

This is the output with this code:

```
0: {date: "2019-07-10", intransit: 1234.23}
1: {date: "2019-07-10", general: 1234.23}
2: {date: "2019-07-12", intransit: 1234.23}
3: {date: "2019-07-12", general: 1234.23}
```

As you can see date is duplicated, how may I merge/groups boths but without losing the value?
The information must to be like this:

```
0: {date: "2019-07-10", intransit: 1234.23, general: 1234.23}
2: {date: "2019-07-12", intransit: 1234.23, general: 1234.23}
```

In case you can't visualize the structure from Elastic, this is the output from console.log(values):

```
_source: {date: "2019-07-10", assessment: 123.12, 
warehouse: {id: 1, name: "General"}
```

I have tried with Lodash/UnderscoreJS, loops etc... and nothing. If you know any advice or anything about this, would be apreciate.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `reduce()` to create  groupBy object or Map using dates as keys then return the `values`

```js
const data = [ {date: "2019-07-10", intransit: 1234.23}, {date: "2019-07-10", general:1234.23}, {date: "2019-07-12", intransit: 1234.23},{date: "2019-07-12", general:1234.23}]

const res = Object.values(
  data.reduce((a, c) => {
    a[c.date] = a[c.date] || {};
    Object.assign(a[c.date], c);
    return a;
  }, {})
)


console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why you had negative vote, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on [Lodash-fp](https://gist.github.com/jfmengels/6b973b69c491375117dc)

```
const dateMerger = _.flow([
    _.groupBy('date'),
    _.values,
    _.map(_.reduce(_.merge, {}))
]);

const dateData = [
    {date: "2019-07-10", intransit: 1234.23},
    {date: "2019-07-10", general: 1234.23},
    {date: "2019-07-12", intransit: 1234.23},
    {date: "2019-07-12", general: 1234.23}
];

console.log(dateMerger(dateData));
```

[image]

Comment: I got this error: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined, maybe Am I not using the the real URL for lodash?
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.14/lodash.min.js"></script>
{{--    <script src="{{asset('vendor/handsontable/0.34.5/test/lib/lodash.underscore.js')}}"></script>--}}

Comment: No, it's Lodash-fp, a full functional programmming variant of classic Lodash.Insert this `<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>` to test CDN. Documentation here `https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide`